# How to pass null or empty value to CommandParameter in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I need to pass a null or empty string to a `System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.CommandParameter` object for run a PowerShell script

This is my current code:

```
using rs = System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
rs.CommandParameter cmdAgreementName = new rs.CommandParameter("AgreementName", "");
cmdScript.Parameters.Add(cmdAgreementName);
```

The problem is that I get the following error message:

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

How can I resolve it?

Comment: `rs.CommandParameter("AgreementName");`? But exactly at which statement is the error thrown?

Comment: Is it possible that the empty string is successfully getting passed to the script, but the script produces that error when you pass the empty string to it?

Comment: It appears CommandParameter has a .Value property.  Have you tried putting that after the ("AgreementName, "") ?